# Help with circuit for school

Tags: electromagnetism, detection, detector, field-strength, electric-field

I am doing a project for school with two friends.  We are going to make a DIY metal detector.  We are using a source as our circuit. Can someone help us describe what is happening in the circuit?

[image]

Comment: Where's the bit in that circuit that senses the metal?  It just looks like a fixed oscillator to me.

Comment: At a quick glance, this just looks like a standard astable 555 circuit. Theres thousands of articles and pages dedicated to the 555 timer online. Google Astable 555 circuit and you will get all the information you could need on how this circuit works

Comment: See this http://www.123seminarsonly.com/Seminar-Reports/049/110814953-555-Timer-and-Its-Applications.pdf and this http://www.sophphx.caltech.edu/Physics_5/Data_sheets/555appnote.pdf

Comment: Note that pin 2 should be connected to pin 6, not pin 7.